# filter row in data.table using object with same name as column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table  `dt` with column names `x` and `y`. I also have object `y` that I need to use to filter some rows in `dt` using the values in `dt$y`. Unfortunately, since one of the columns has the same name as the object, I can't make it work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table( x = c(1:4), 
                  y = letters[1:4])
y <- "c"

dt[y == y]
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 a
#> 2: 2 b
#> 3: 3 c
#> 4: 4 d
dt[y == (y)]
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 a
#> 2: 2 b
#> 3: 3 c
#> 4: 4 d
dt[y == ..y]
#> Error in eval(stub[[3L]], x, enclos): object '..y' not found
eval(quote(y))
#> [1] "c"
dt[y == eval(quote(y))]
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 a
#> 2: 2 b
#> 3: 3 c
#> 4: 4 d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

PS: I apologize if this question has been asked somewhere else. I searched for an answer, but I could not find it.

Comment: I agree with sindri_baldur that you *could* use `get`, but I just don't see why this would be necessary. I suspect your actual problem is a bit different. Perhaps you could explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use `get()` and the `env` argument:

```
dt[y == get('y', env = -2)]
#    x y
# 1: 3 c
```

Beware this makes certain assumptions about your setup. If your `y` is defined in the global environment as in your example, then a safer solution (as suggested by Ian Campell) would be:

```
dt[y == get('y', env = globalenv())]
```

Comment: Might be a bit safer to use `globalenv()` in place of `-2`. It could get messy if there are functions inside `I`.